В чем практическая разница применения отдельной таблицы или MATERIALIZED VIEW
Дана достаточно раскидистая структура данных большого объема. Логика моей программы требует работы с определенной выборкой из этих таблиц. Выборка происходит достаточно долгое время и, чтобы ускорить процесс, я решил, что нужна временная таблица, в которую я один раз сделаю выборку и затем буду общаться только с этой временной таблицей, периодически ее обновляя. Но, почитав документацию к PostgreSQL, я нашел такой инструмент как MATERIALIZED VIEW, который, судя по тому, что я понял как раз подходит для моих целей.
Вопрос
В чем практическая разница (по вашему опыту и знаниям) в применении отдельной временной таблицы против применения  MATERIALIZED VIEW. Документацию я читал, та разница, которая описана в первом же абзаце мне понятна. Меня интересуют другие моменты, например, что будет быстрее работать или что практически удобнее.

Насколько я понимаю, тут разница именно в том, устраивает вас слегка устаревший кэш ваших данных или нет. И каков вообще ваш процесс использования этих данных.

Если вы делаете какой-то отчёт или группу отчётов и для вас не критично подождать пока сформируется временная таблица, а потом вы сгенерируете из неё некие отчёты и удалите эту временную таблицу - ну, ок, временная таблица для вас самое то.
Если же вам нужно периодически получать какие-то отчёты по данным, при этом вы не хотите долго ждать, пока данные обновляются, а получить отчёты как можно быстрее, пусть данные при этом будут не самые свежие - вот тут materialized view по идее самое то. Это как бы кэш ваших данных, обновляемый "по запросу".

Конечно, такой устаревающий кэш можно сделать и в таблице БД, казалось бы какая разница тогда? Но разница всё же есть. Временные таблицы на то и временные, что они не должны долго жить. Если вы хотите пользоваться таблицей всё время, то это уже постоянная таблица.
Ок, вы можете сделать постоянную таблицу и обновлять её через какую-то процедуру. Чем это плохо? На мой взгляд это плохо тем, что у вас два разных объекта в БД и вы должны знать, какая между ними связь. Отдельно таблица и отдельно процедура, которая обновляет эту таблицу. В случае же MV у вас таблица и процедура обновления - это один объект, есть чёткая инструкция, как вам обновить данные в MV, эта процедура одинаковая для любого MV, всё чётко и понятно.
Кроме того, не знаю как Postgresql, но во многих продвинутых БД есть разные стратегии обновления MV. Они могут обновляться автоматически, например, при обновлении данных в таблицах, на которых они построены. Или, если не путаю, то по времени - скажем, раз в сутки. Что в общем удобно. Не нужно настраивать ещё и запуск процедуры по времени, сразу всё зашито в MV - и данные, и процедура их обновления, и стратегия/расписание обновления. По-моему это просто удобно.

Исчерпывающе, благодарю! Попытался поискать автоматическое обновление MV средствами PostgreSQL на серверной стороне, не нашел, коллеги рекомендуют cron. Но, на самом деле, для моей логики это как раз не нужно. Мне правильнее обновлять по запросу.

@AlexeyTrukhanov Да, в постгре похоже такого ещё не сделали. Вот в Oracle там да. Ну может и тут допилят потом.
